# SSH speed greatly improved via ProxyCommand - but why?

Tags: ssh, networking, netcat

**The TL;DR version**

[Watch this ASCII cast](https://asciinema.org/a/rMpxMHNXIBAaOiBvSjAISbLBU) or [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tT0s4pz9hIQ6MPcYnVEE5uMsqfsCyJiX/view) - then come up with any reasons why this is happening. The text description that follows provides more context.

**Details of the setup**

- Machine 1 is an Arch Linux laptop, on which `ssh` is spawned, connecting to an Armbian-running SBC (an Orange PI Zero).
- The SBC itself is connected via Ethernet to a DSL router, and has an IP of 192.168.1.150
- The laptop is connected to the router over WiFi - using an official Raspberry PI WiFi dongle.
- There's also another laptop (Machine 2) connected via Ethernet to the DSL router.

[image: Topology]

**Benchmarking the link with iperf3**

When benchmarked with `iperf3`, the link between the laptop and the SBC is less than the theoretical 56 MBits/sec - as expected, since this is a WiFi connection within a very "crowded 2.4GHz" *(apartment building)*.

More specifically: after running `iperf3 -s` on the SBC, the following commands are executed on the laptop:

```
# iperf3 -c 192.168.1.150
Connecting to host 192.168.1.150, port 5201
[  5] local 192.168.1.89 port 57954 connected to 192.168.1.150 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  2.99 MBytes  25.1 Mbits/sec    0    112 KBytes       
...
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  28.0 MBytes  23.5 Mbits/sec    5             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.8 MBytes  23.4 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.

# iperf3 -c 192.168.1.150 -R
Connecting to host 192.168.1.150, port 5201
Reverse mode, remote host 192.168.1.150 is sending
[  5] local 192.168.1.89 port 57960 connected to 192.168.1.150 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  3.43 MBytes  28.7 Mbits/sec                  
...                
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  39.2 MBytes  32.9 Mbits/sec  375             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  37.7 MBytes  31.6 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

So basically, uploading to the SBC reaches about 24MBits/sec, and downloading from it (`-R`) reaches 32MBits/sec.

**Benchmarking with SSH**

Given that, let's see how SSH fares. I've first experienced the problems that led to this post when using `rsync` and `borgbackup` - both of them using SSH as a transport layer... So let's see how SSH performs on the same link:

```
# cat /dev/urandom | \
    pv -ptebar | \
    ssh  root@192.168.1.150 'cat >/dev/null'
20.3MiB 0:00:52 [ 315KiB/s] [ 394KiB/s]
```

Well, that's an abysmal speed! Much slower than the expected link speed...
*(In case you are not aware of `pv -ptevar`: it displays the current and average rate of data going through it. In this case, we see that reading from `/dev/urandom` and sending the data over SSH to the SBC is on average reaching 400KB/s - i.e. 3.2MBits/sec, a far lesser figure than the expected 24MBits/sec.)*

Why is our link running at 13% of its capacity?

Is it perhaps our `/dev/urandom`'s fault?

```
# cat /dev/urandom | pv -ptebar > /dev/null
834MiB 0:00:04 [ 216MiB/s] [ 208MiB/s]
```

Nope, definitely not.

Is it perhaps the SBC itself? Perhaps it's too slow to process?
Let's try running the same SSH command (i.e. sending data to the SBC) but this time from another machine (Machine 2) that is connected over the Ethernet:

```
# cat /dev/urandom | \
    pv -ptebar | \
    ssh  root@192.168.1.150 'cat >/dev/null'
240MiB 0:00:31 [10.7MiB/s] [7.69MiB/s]
```

Nope, this works fine - the SSH daemon on the SBC can (easily) handle the 11MBytes/sec (i.e. the 100MBits/sec) that it's Ethernet link provides.

And is the CPU of the SBC loaded while doing this?

[image: CPU is easily handling it]

Nope.

So...

- network-wise (as per `iperf3`) we should be able to do 10x the speed
- our CPU can easily accommodate the load
- ... and we don't involve any other kind of I/O (e.g. drives).

What the heck is happening?

**Netcat and ProxyCommand to the rescue**

Let's try plain old `netcat` connections - do they run as fast as we'd expect?

In the SBC:

```
# nc -l -p 9988 | pv -ptebar > /dev/null
```

In the laptop:

```
# cat /dev/urandom | pv -ptebar | nc 192.168.1.150 9988
117MiB 0:00:33 [3.82MiB/s] [3.57MiB/s]
```

It works! And runs at the expected - much better, 10x better - speed.

So what happens if I run SSH using a ProxyCommand to use nc?

```
# cat /dev/urandom | \
    pv -ptebar | \
    ssh -o "Proxycommand nc %h %p" root@192.168.1.150 'cat >/dev/null'
101MiB 0:00:30 [3.38MiB/s] [3.33MiB/s]
```

Works! 10x speed.

Now I am a bit confused - when using a "naked" `nc` as a `Proxycommand`, aren't you basically doing the exact same thing that SSH does? i.e. creating a socket, connecting to the SBC's port 22, and then shoveling the SSH protocol over it?

Why is there this huge difference in the resulting speed?

P.S. This was not an *academic exercise* - my `borg` backup runs 10 times faster because of this. I just don't know why :-)

**EDIT**: Added a "video" of the process [here](https://asciinema.org/a/rMpxMHNXIBAaOiBvSjAISbLBU). Counting the packets sent from the output of ifconfig, it is clear that in both tests we are sending 40MB of data, transmitting them in approximately 30K packets - just much slower when not using `ProxyCommand`.

Comment: buffering? I would think `nc` uses line buffering, whereas `ssh` has no buffering. So (or if so) the ssh traffic involves more packets.

Comment: i'm no expert but i think orange 0 has only one usb bus controlled by cpu, the network goes through that usb bus, the cpu has to create random number via software ( there is no chip on that kind of architecture who does that via hardware) and at the same time there is the ssh cypher ongoing and  perhaps the ssh compression too.
i didn't check all of this so it's possible i'm saying something wrong.

Comment: @D'ArcyNader: No, I'm afraid you got it wrong. Tbe /dev/urandom happens in the laptop (x86) - and I did the same test from Machine 2 speaking to the SBC, reaching top speeds (100MBits/sec), and thus proving that the SBC has no issue dealing with the traffic. The problem only manifests when SSH is used from the laptop - and when I change the SSH invocation (again, on the laptop side) to use netcat - so still doing dev/urandom and still piping all the data - the problem disappears.

And BTW, the single USB bus is a problem of the Raspberry PIs - not the Orange PIs.

Comment: i'm sorry if i didn't help you. and thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist: The original use case that led me down this rabbit hole was backing things up over rsync and borgbackup. Many tools use SSH as a transport mechanism - and in my case, suffered because of this. If what I am experiencing is, indeed, the "standard" SSH behaviour, then I would expect that submitting pull requests to all backup tools to spawn SSH via a netcat ProxyCommand would instantly speed up backups all over the planet!  I can't believe I made such a "huge" discovery :-) something else must be happening here.

Comment: i did the same test you did. i had no speed issues. i have a laptop on wifi and a raspberry pi b+ running raspbian on the ethernet side.

Comment: @D'ArcyNader Yep - that's why this drives me nuts :-) A "naked" nc in a ProxyCommand shouldn't be *any* different to a plain SSH!  And yet in my configuration it somehow is...  Do you see different speed results in your test if you use ProxyCommand as I did?

Comment: i didn't do the machine2 test because i had no issues.

utente@lambasus:~$ cat /dev/urandom |pv -ptebar | ssh pi@raspytenz 'cat >/dev/null'
 129MiB 0:00:59 [2,18MiB/s] [2,18MiB/s] [                            <=>       ]

-------
utente@lambasus:~$ cat /dev/urandom |pv -ptebar | ssh -o "Proxycommand nc %h %p" pi@raspytenz 'cat >/dev/null'
 140MiB 0:00:59 [2,36MiB/s] [2,36MiB/s] [                            <=>       ]

Comment: @D'ArcyNader Thanks - at least I know I am not insane :-)  That is, that what I am experiencing is indeed bizzare. I hope someone will suggest something, because I am honestly out of ideas. My backup processes work fine, so there's no "emergency" - but I hate mysteries :-)

Comment: I suggest you use (e.g.) `iptables` or `tcpdump` for counting the IP packets sent and received in both cases.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: I counted the packets via `ifconfig`'s output (`grep`-ing for "packets"). Here's a [video of the process](https://asciinema.org/a/rMpxMHNXIBAaOiBvSjAISbLBU). In both cases, around 30K pkts are transmitted. What next?

Comment: So I would guess the problem is SSH itself, not the SSH network traffic. What happens if you transfer data via SSH to the localhost?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I am unsure what you mean - the SSH server of the SBC? If so, note that using the ProxyCommand on the laptop is in no way changing the SSH server of the SBC (and yet drastically improves the speed)... 

Then again, if you are referring to the SSH client of the laptop, well...  `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=200 of=/dev/shm/data ;  pv /dev/shm/data | ssh ttsiod@localhost 'cat >/dev/null` -  gives 144MBytes/sec...

Comment: @HaukeLaging And if you meant doing the test from within the SBC: "pv /dev/shm/data | ssh root@localhost 'cat >/dev/null'
 40MiB 0:00:07 [5.32MiB/s]"

Comment: Any kind of traffic shaping in effect on the laptop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75374/discussion-between-ttsiodras-and-hauke-laging).

Comment: Just a small tip for the future: instead of `cat file | program` you can simply do `<file program`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Many thanks to the people who submitted ideas in the comments. I went through them all:

**Recording packets with tcpdump and comparing the contents in WireShark**

```
# tcpdump -i wlan0 -w good.ssh & \
     cat signature | ssh -o "ProxyCommand nc %h %p" \
        root@192.168.1.150 'cat | md5sum' ; \
     killall tcpdump
# tcpdump -i wlan0 -w bad.ssh & \
     cat signature | ssh root@192.168.1.150 'cat | md5sum' ; \
     killall tcpdump
```

There was no difference of any importance in the recorded packets.

**Checking for traffic shaping**

Had no idea about this - but after looking at the "tc" manpage, I was able to verify that

- `tc filter show` returns nothing
- `tc class show` returns nothing
- `tc qdisc show`

...returns these:

```
qdisc noqueue 0: dev lo root refcnt 2
qdisc noqueue 0: dev docker0 root refcnt 2
qdisc fq_codel 0: dev wlan0 root refcnt 2 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5.0ms interval 100.0ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn
```

...which don't seem to differentiate between "ssh" and "nc" - in fact, I am not even sure if traffic shaping can operate on the process level (I'd expect it to work on addresses/ports/Differentiated Services field in IP Header).

**Debian Chroot, to avoid potential "cleverness" in Arch Linux SSH client**

Nope, same results.

**Finally - Nagle**

Performing an strace in the sender...

```
pv data | strace -T -ttt -f ssh 192.168.1.150 'cat | md5sum' 2>bad.log
```

...and looking at what exactly happens on the socket that transmits the data across, I noticed this "setup" before the actual transmitting starts:

```
1522665534.007805 getsockopt(3, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [0], [4]) = 0 <0.000025>
1522665534.007899 setsockopt(3, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0 <0.000021>
```

This sets up the SSH socket to disable Nagle's algorithm. You can Google and read all about it - but what it means, is that SSH is giving priority to responsiveness over bandwidth - it instructs the kernel to transmit anything written on this socket immediately and not "delay" waiting for acknowledgments from the remote.

What this means, in plain terms, is that in its default configuration, SSH is NOT a good way to transport data across - not when the link used is a slow one (which is the case for many WiFi links). If we are sending packets over the air that are "mostly headers", the bandwidth is wasted!

To prove that this was indeed the culprit, I used LD_PRELOAD to "drop" this specific syscall:

```
$ cat force_nagle.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int (*osetsockopt) (int socket, int level, int option_name,
           const void *option_value, socklen_t option_len) = NULL;

int setsockopt(int socket, int level, int option_name,
           const void *option_value, socklen_t option_len)
{
    int ret;
    if (!osetsockopt) {
        osetsockopt = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "setsockopt");
    }

    if (option_name == TCP_NODELAY) {
        puts("No, Mr Nagle stays.");
        return 0;
    }
    ret = osetsockopt(socket, level, option_name, option_value, option_len);
    return ret;
}

$ gcc -fPIC -D_GNU_SOURCE -shared -o force_nagle.so force_nagle.c -ldl

$ pv /dev/shm/data | LD_PRELOAD=./force_nagle.so ssh root@192.168.1.150 'cat >/dev/null'
No, Mr Nagle stays.
No, Mr Nagle stays.
 100MiB 0:00:29 [3.38MiB/s] [3.38MiB/s] [================================>] 100%
```

There - perfect speed (well, just as fast as iperf3).

**Morale of the story**

Never give up :-)

And if you do use tools like `rsync` or `borgbackup` that transport their data over SSH, and your link is a slow one, try stopping SSH from disabling Nagle (as shown above) - or using `ProxyCommand` to switch SSH to connect via `nc`. This can be automated in your $HOME/.ssh/config:

```
$ cat .ssh/config
...
Host orangepi
    Hostname 192.168.1.150
    User root
    Port 22
    # Compression no
    # Cipher None
    ProxyCommand nc %h %p
...
```

...so that all future uses of "orangepi" as a target host in ssh/rsync/borgbackup will henceforth use `nc` to connect (and therefore leave Nagle alone).

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life! Have you tried contacting the ssh folks to understand why there isn't a setting to control this?

Comment: I am glad my findings helped you as well! As for contacting the SSH folks, I tried, yes - but nothing happened, in the end:  https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2848

Comment: Added myself to the bug. Who knows, something might happen eventually! Great investigation, in any case.